# Как получить ответ пользователя telegram bot (на python)

Tags: telebot, telegram, бот

Всем добрый день. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой при написании telegram bot с помощью библиотеки telebot:
Если вкратце - есть программа, которая задает вопрос с вариантами ответов и ждет ответа пользователя.

Условно:

```
question = 'Как дела?'
buttons = ['хорошо','плохо']
answer = ask_a_question(message, question, buttons)
```

В моем случае, бот получает вопрос и кнопки. Задает вопрос, но потом не дожидаясь ответа register_next_step_handler возвращает текст предыдущего ответа.

Пробовал вызывать функцию напрямую(с тем же результатом) или обработать с помощью:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
@bot.callback_query_handler(func= lambda call: True)
```

К сожалению не понимаю как заставить бота "ждать" ответ пользователя, чтобы потом обработать полученный message.text.
Вот упрощенный вариант кода:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from config import bot_token

bot = telebot.TeleBot(f'{bot_token}')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def start(message):
    question = 'Как дела?'
    buttons = ['хорошо','плохо']
    answer = ask_a_question(message, question, buttons)

    # Вот здесь пробую получить от пользователя ответ

    if answer == buttons[0] or answer == buttons[1]:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я получил ответ')
    else:
        raise ValueError('ничего не получил')
  
def ask_a_question(message, quest, butt):
    question = quest
    buttons = butt
    rmk = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    for button in buttons:
        rmk.add(types.KeyboardButton(str(button)))
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, question, reply_markup=rmk)
    return bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_text)


def get_text(message):
    answer = message.text
    return answer

bot.polling()
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь.